# Windows 10 Professional concurrent RDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have two Surface 3 tablets both running Windows 10 Professional.

I want to know if there's a way to remotely connect to one tablet (using Windows built-in RDP client) and be able to use them both in a concurrent way. Something similar to what TeamViewer does, you can see and also interact with what the remote user is doing.

Right now when I remotely connect to any Windows machine that system will automatically lock the screen. If I manually unlock it the remote session will end. Is this a security option or a Windows 10 limitation (maybe licence?)?

Comment: No, that is how RDP works. RDP is a feature to take over a session, not to share screens. if you want both the user and the remote person to interact with the computer, RDP is not the tool. Only in a server environment with the Terminal Servers role installed, RDP technology can be used to shadow a user session, but that still exclude the local user. Its just 2 remote users in that case.

Comment: If there is a local and remote user you can use Windows Remote Assistance (quick assist) for this. Pain to setup a connection though.

Answer (score 0):

RDP shadowing works on client OS' as well and let's you control or just view a user session, just like Teamviewer.
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33768/Using-RDP-shadowing-for-convenient-user-support-and-remote-control.html describes all the details. Shortened version:
1 configure a GPO at the target ->gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Remote Desktop Services / Remote Desktop Session Host / Connections and enable the policy "Set rules for remote control of Remote Desktop Services user sessions". Here, you can (and should for your scenario) choose to not require any confirmation
2 enable the built-in firewall allow-rule at the target called "Remote desktop - Shadow (TCP-in)"

That's all.

Comment: Sorry, I have to vote this down. RDP Shadowing only shadows an existing remote session, not a local user session. In addition, this answer lacks any form of explaining how to set it up in case I would've been wrong.

Comment: LPchip, that is not correct. Undo your downvote if you can after confirming it. Read my article https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33768/Using-RDP-shadowing-for-convenient-user-support-and-remote-control.html

Comment: So apparently it is possible after a lot of configuration that is required which also means Windows 10 Professional or higher is required. My downvote stands though. If you edit your question and include all steps necessary to make this work, I'll change it into an upvote. (Also, I cannot retract my downvote until an edit is made due to timeout)

Comment: Done. And please note that although as stated, he has Pro, Pro is not required since the GPO is registry based, it can be set on home, too: https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer::TS_RemoteControl_2

Comment: I've removed the downvote, but the answer is still not that good to warrant an upvote. Its hard to read and misses all the steps for actually connecting. Also, please understand that answers with a link are considered inadequate as a link can become invalid which invalidates the answer, so I only judge on the answer itself, not the link provided.

Comment: Followed the guide but no luck. I've set the remote rule to "Full Control with user's permission: ..." + restart, started mstsc using `/v:PC1 /shadow:1 /control` params (yes, I have the same session ID, and I've replaced PC1 with the corresponding computer name). I'm getting: `Shadow Error - This computer name is invalid.`. One thing I noticed: when enabling that remote session rule, under "supported on" Windows 10 is not present... can you confirm this setting works on Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: Marius, I have reviewed this. On a workgroup (non-domain), you need to add the following: open port 445 (file and printer sharing) on the target. Create the registry key (DWord32) "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy " and set it to 1 at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System. Then restart the machine and of course mind that the account you are connecting with is admin on the remote machine as well. Yes, works on current Win10 21H2 and Win11.